# php automatically creating hyperlink based on filename with spaces

Tags: php, file, hyperlink, directory

Probably just something small, but I am using the below code to read the files inside of a directory and print them out as of a hyperlink to itself.

It prints out the complete file name, but it creates an incomplete hyperlink using only characters up to the first space. The question is how to create a functional hyperlink for a file with spaces in it?

```
$dir = '.';
$dh = opendir($dir);
$file_count = 0;
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = $file;
    $file_count += 1;
    echo $file;
}
for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x += 1) {
    echo "<a href=$files[$x]>" . "$files[$x]" . "</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/urlencode - If you create a hyperlink (URL/URI), you need to follow the rules otherwise you are speaking a language different to the browser with whom you want to speak. Take care. And as you output HTML, you also need to create valid HTML. http://php.net/htmlspecialchars Take care.

Comment: `<a href="value of attribute goes in quotes">Follow HTML standards</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to add quotes to the HREF attribute inside the anchor tag:

```
 echo "<a href='$files[$x]'>$files[$x]</a><br>";
```

The client may think the part of the filename following the space is another attribute. (You may also want to use htmlentities() to escape the filenames inside the href attribute.)

Comment: Only until you have a file-name containing not a space but a single quote... - For the exact same reason you would then run into the same problem a second time. What you actually need is `urlencode` in the first place, e.g. for special characters in filenames that you want to keep in the next request.

Comment: @hakre - You're right. The most secure way is probably: '<a href="'.htmlentities(urlencode($files[$x])).'">'  That handles non-html safe characters and non-URL safe characters.

Comment: Yes, the attribute value should be also passed through `htmlentities` in case it's something that needs. For an `urlencoded` value this is *not the case*, so your suggestion is misguiding - it shows that you don't know what you do and for what reason fully (yes, these computers are damn strict at some points ;) ). See http://eval.in/6016 - Also if you think that is more secure, please answer that way, you should always provide the most stable code as answers, not just a patchwork code that is fragile and will break down next time soon.

Answer (score 2):

```
$dir = '.';
$dh = dir($dir);
while (FALSE !== ($file = $dh->read())) 
{
    if ('.' !== $file[0]) // ignore any entry that begins with a '.'
        echo "<a href='" . urlencode($file) . "'>". $file . "</a><br />\n";
}
$dh->close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I already suggested the usage of [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) and [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) in a comment above.

I also suggest that you make use of [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/FilesystemIterator) because it's very convenient to use in your case:

```
$dir = '.';
$files = new FilesystemIterator($dir);

foreach ($files as $path => $fileinfo) {
    $name  = $fileinfo->getBasename();
    $url   = urlencode($name);
    $label = htmlspecialchars($name);
    printf("<a href=\"%s\">%s</a><br>\n", $url, $label);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `glob();`

```
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
        echo "<a href=\"$filename\">$filename</a> <br>";
}
```

You can specify by extension, or what I have specified `*.*` this will show all files on their own hyperlink.

Comment: I will use this method. It is a lot more simple. Thanks!

Comment: But it will still break your HTML for the reasons you ask in the question. Your problem is not getting the directory listing, but outputting it. After you've got it to work, you can choose how you want to improve getting the directory listing.